# Saving LastModified Date alongside User details

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I'm using Entity Framework and was wondering what the easiest way to save a `LastModified` date field in the database alongside user details (Active Directory).

I first thought of using a Database Trigger to update the field, but I don't think there's any way to retrieve the authenticated user in order to identify them to that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the authenticated user is actually the user that the actions are performed on behalf of in SQL Server, you can actually get the current user using the builtin function [SYSTEM_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) or [CURRENT_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx) in a trigger.

For example:

```
UPDATE (appropriate table name)
   SET LastModified = GETDATE(),
       LastModifiedBy = SYSTEM_USER
 WHERE (appropriate where clause)
```

Comment: This isn't really what I'm after unfortunately. Rather than return the `SYSTEM_USER` or `CURRENT_USER` I'd want to actually return the authenticated user from AD, which is going to be different to the user connecting to SQL server.